# APNS Compatibility between all iOS Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, xcode8, ios10

So recently I had updated my application to `iOS 10/ Xcode 8`,

Now I'm having problem in sending push notification to iOS 10 device because

**The iOS 10 payload should follow**

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "body":"YOUR_MESSAGE."
        },
    "badge": 1
    },
    "YOUR_VARIABLE" : "YOUR VALUE"
}
```

**where iOS < 9 follow**

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "YOUR_MESSAGE.",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "default"
    },
    "YOUR_VARIABLE" : "YOUR VALUE"
}
```

So how can I get push notification working for all the devices with minimal changes on Application/Service. Even little help is very appreciable

Comment: You need set condition for iOS10 version and you can access your pay load base on condition.

Comment: Actually `alert` as dictionary or string is supposed to work in both iOS 9 and 10. But you could send the system version to the server while registering the device and compose the payload according to the version.

Comment: @mitulmarsonia the solution you suggested was I'm already having in my mind like sending the iOS version and handling accordingly in service,But still is there is any other way to handle these things

Comment: @vadian will it work ?,From Application side everything is handled by it's own,But in service side I need to change,Right ?

Comment: @holex May I known what you are referring to ?

Comment: From my knowledge you don't need to change anything if you don't want to take advantage of the enhanced keys and their appearance in iOS 10

Comment: @radkrish i don't think so any other solution.

Comment: @vadian You are right,This works fine with the same payload in iOS 10 if I directly send to the apple server,But if I use some third part application then it's failing with that payload.

Comment: @all Thanks everyone giving some time